# Ansible return value - Extract a specific line

Tags: ansible

So I got my role working now, the result is now in "var" and I see an output. First of all here is the role which I have written:

```
- name: create a server
  os_server:
    state: present
    flavor: m1.nano
    auth:
      auth_url: ****
      username: ****
      password: ****
      project_name: admin
      domain_id: ****
    name: ansibletest
#   region_name: RegionOne
    image: 4e7ab5c8-4b39-4c77-b68d-cf2ea7e1df1a
    key_name: ansible
    timeout: 200
    auto_ip: yes
    nics:
      - net-id: a5a73ab9-3ee5-49a6-bea0-f44f9e376ca0    
  register: result
- debug: var=result
```

And I get a long output of this like this one:

```
TASK [openstack : debug] *******************************************************
ok: [172.20.22.21] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "id": "6f40f396-7ef8-4e0e-9769-2b9cea898269",
            .........
            "accessIPv4": "172.20.22.58",
            .......
                    {
                        ..........
                    },
                    {
                        ............
                        "addr": "172.20.22.58",
                        ......
                    }
                ]
            },
            ........
            },
            "interface_ip": "172.20.22.58",
            .................
                    .............
                ]
            },
            "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [],
            "private_v4": "10.0.100.92",
            "progress": 0,
            "public_v4": "172.20.22.58",
            ................
                {
                   ...........
    }
}
```

I only need the IP address (in this case it's the `172.20.22.58` contained in `"accessIPv4"`) - is there any way to "filter" the output to just retrieve this value?

Comment: Try result.interface_ip

Answer (score 1):

You can access it using Ansible's dictionary access methods. You've mangled the output in your question too much to really know what the output looks like but if it looks like:

```
"result": {
    "changed": false,
    "id": "6f40f396-7ef8-4e0e-9769-2b9cea898269",
    "output": {
        ...
        "accessIPv4": "172.20.22.58",
        ...
```

Then you should be able to access the value with `result.output.accessIPv4`.

Comment: thats for the quick response.
so do you mean i need to do it like this?

` register: result
- debug: var=result.output.accessIPv4`

cause when i do this i get the message:

`TASK [openstack : debug] *******************************************************
ok: [172.20.22.21] => {
    "result.output.accessIPv4": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
`

Comment: Notice how I said "if you're output looks like" and provided an example and then showed how you would access that value. Because you've mangled your output (and I don't use OpenStack) I don't know know what the output actually looks like. If `accessIPv4` was a child of `id` then it would be `result.id.accessIPv4`

Comment: yeah okay sorry. so here we go:
`{
 "changed": true,
 "id": "f5b9401f-507c-459d-8a9e-5124a39f27e4",
 "openstack": {
  "HUMAN_ID": true,
  "NAME_ATTR": "name",
  "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL",
                   ......
  "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2016-07-25T06:40:40.000000",
  "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null,
  "accessIPv4": "172.20.22.58",`

i fixed it with "debug var=result.openstack.accessIPv4" 
Jesus Christ, this tiny problem made such a big load of work... it works!! thaks mate! YOur tip with the "child" was great

Comment: If you edit your question to include the parent element (`openstack`) in your output then this will be a lot easier to understand for anyone else coming along with the same problem.